# Align top of inline element background

Tags: html, css

This question is related to this one : [Why the computed height of inline nonreplaced element differs between browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127614/why-the-computed-height-of-inline-nonreplaced-element-differs-between-browsers)

I have an inline element on which I use a background color to give a highlight effect. (This is the legend of a picture.)

I cannot setup exactly the rendering of the background height, as the font is rendering differently across browsers. This is not a problem if this is slightly different.

What I only need is that the top of my first line background is aligned with the picture on the left, in my jsfiddle below, white and blue need to be aligned. Is there any way to do this with CSS ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="float"></div>
    <span>Et quoniam mirari posse quosdam peregrinos existimo haec lecturos forsitan, si contigerit, quamobrem cum oratio ad ea monstranda deflexerit quae Romae gererentur, nihil praeter seditiones narratur et tabernas et vilitates harum similis alias, summatim causas perstringam nusquam a veritate sponte propria digressurus.</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.main {
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
} 

div.float {
    min-height: 50px;
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

span {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-color: blue;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0ne3pay2/4/

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is to use `display:table-cell;` with the `float div` and the `span` elements, you can see it here:

```css
div.main {
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
} 

div.float {
    min-height: 50px;
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    display:table-cell;
}

span {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-color: blue;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="float"></div>
    <span>Et quoniam mirari posse quosdam peregrinos existimo haec lecturos forsitan, si contigerit, quamobrem cum oratio ad ea monstranda deflexerit quae Romae gererentur, nihil praeter seditiones narratur et tabernas et vilitates harum similis alias, summatim causas perstringam nusquam a veritate sponte propria digressurus.</span>
</div>
```

And that will give you a better display for the `span` where you can see it as a block instead of lines.

**EDIT:**

If you don't want your `span` to be rendered as a block so you just need to add  `margin-top: 3px;` to your `float div` because the problem here is caused by the `line-height: 1.5;` of your span, you have two choices either to remove it or add the margin to the div.

Here's the [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/0ne3pay2/6/).

Comment: But I don't want to see it as a block. I want to have space between lines, and just highlight the text so the background ends at the end of the text.

Comment: @Guilro take a look at my EDIT.

Answer (score -1):

```
div.main {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
span {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thisizmonster/0ne3pay2/5/

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I intend to do. I want to give it a "highlight" style, so the background ends at the end of the text and there is white space between lines.